# Geometric definition of the stable commutator length

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, surfaces

In his [book](http://math.uchicago.edu/~dannyc/scl/scl.pdf.gz), D.Calegari proves the equivalence of the algebraic and geometric definitions of stable commutator length (Proposition 2.10, p. 15). I actually have some difficulties in understanding the proof. For example, when he says that the inequality in one direction is "obvious," he has the following argument:

> $cl(a^n) \leq g$ if and only if there is an admissible map $f : S \rightarrow X$, where S has exactly one boundary component and satisfies $n(S) = n$ and $2g − 1 = -\chi^-(S)$. Hence $\lim_n cl(a^n)/n \geq \inf_S -\chi^- (S)/2n(S)$. *[However, I do not see, why it is so.]* We must have
>   $$
> \lim_n cl(a^n)/n \geq \inf_S (2g-1)/2n,
> $$

but why should this inequality hold?

In the second part of the proof, he also says that adding a $1$-handle to a surface increases genus by $1$ and reduces the number of boundary components by $1$. It is clear with genus, but why should it reduce the number of boundary components?

Comment: Adding a $1$-handle should increase the genus *or* the number of boundary components, but not both.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip He uses $1$-handles to connect up the different boundary components. Why does such operation reduce the number of boundary components by one?

Comment: If a $1$-handle connects two different boundary components, then those two components have been absorbed into one along the boundary of the $1$-handle. If the $1$-handle connects the same boundary component to itself, then it increases genus.